# How to create one service in nestJS that called first before anything?

Tags: nestjs

I want to create one service in nestJS application that called before anything. 
I have one function that listen azure service bus in nestJS. So, whenever this application is up and running, I need to call this function and start to listen.
So, how and where should I create that service method?

Comment: Can't you just call it in the same place where you start your nest server?

Comment: If not, take a look at lifecycle events https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/lifecycle-events

Comment: @UrošAnđelić I am a new at nestJS. I have tried that onModuleInIt in app.module.ts but still it is not hitting that function just after running.

Comment: Did you checked the constructor usage to call methods on start ?

Comment: Yes I did, but for that, I need to trigger some GET, POST event manually, constructor is not called just after nestJS server is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide a callback in app.listen function in your **main.ts** file to write your post initialization code.

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
   
  ...
   
  await app.listen(3000, () => { console.log('Executed after App is Up'); });
}
bootstrap();
```